# Android: how to use view states with nested drawable resources?

Tags: android, android-resources

I'm trying to create complex drawable with one picture inside changing with main view state change. My current resource looks like that

```
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <selector>
                    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_activated_icon" />
                    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_default_icon" />
                </selector>
...
```

Next I use it as src for my ImageView.
The whole drawable renders fine but the selector ignores setActive() call on the ImageView and always displays "default" icon.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD**

So, here goes the desired drawable hierarchy:

```
layer-list
  transition
    background1
    background2
  image
```

I was unable to activate transition animation in this case so I moved the transition to the upper level:

```
transition
  layer-list
    background1
    image   
  layer-list
    background2
    image   (the same image!)
```

So, how can I implement the first layout and be able both to control the transition and to change source for the image?

Comment: Do you want your ImageView to change on user interaction (ie press/focus), or do you want it to change based on your code (ie state changing, can be based on user actions)?

Comment: Both. Technically it will work like some kind of play/pause button: change it's appearance when user clicks it or when background process started from another place.
Now i use a workaround with another view with changing image behind, but it's interesting to find the simplest way =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you want to be able to control the drawables manually, and have them react to state changes. To my knowledge, it is **bad** practice to try to set a fake state (pressed/focused/etc) on a `View`, so I would recommend you don't try to do that. I haven't done this before, but I can't see why it couldn't be done. My idea would be to create a single `LevelList` of `StateList`s for this button/image.

The `LevelList` would provide you to have control over what "theme" the button/image has depending on the level you set it to using `setLevel()`. Each level would point to a "themed" `StateList` that would have different "themed" drawables for all the various states (pressed/focused/etc).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LevelList
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/state_list_icon_default" />   
    <item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/state_list_icon_another_style_1" />   
    <item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/state_list_icon_another_style_2" />    
</level-list>
```

Your `state_list_icon_default` would have your default drawables, like this (it's up to you what states you want to have drawables for):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_default_icon_pressed" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_default_icon_focused" /> 
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/img_default_icon_disabled_focused" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/img_default_icon_disabled" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_default_icon"/> 
</selector>
```

Here's some tutorials to see more in depth implementations.

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com/2010/10/progress-bar-implementation-using-level.html
http://sermojohn.wordpress.com/2012/02/04/using-a-state-list-drawable-as-a-button-background-image/

Comment: Thanks! I just replaced my selector with level-list, now I can call setLevel on my transition element to control the selector.